# How to import a jQuery plugin into a babel app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, jquery-plugins, babeljs

So I have a modern javascript app build using ES6 modules and transpiled by babel.

In this app, I need to use a [jQuery plugin](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick) for some DOM manipulations. I don't want to globally expose jQuery and then load the plugin code into the document using a script tag. Instead, I want the plugin to be available only inside a module:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
// some magic importing pluginName

$('#element').pluginName();   // how to make this work?
```

Of course plugin is not a module and it needs the `$` variable to be present when instantiating.

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar I can't find a way of importing the plugin locally (so it's visible inside a module only).  The only option I have is to expose `$` globally and to insert a script tag with the plugin into the DOM. I have some concerns against thta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to require the plugin:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
require('path-to-plugin');

$('#element').pluginName();
```

Comment: I would suggest you to import `jQuery` rather than `$`.