# React: Add jquery needed by another library

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, trumbowyg

I want to use [the library Trumbowyg](https://github.com/RD17/react-trumbowyg) in my react project. But the problem is the library throws error `jQuery is not defined`.

I found info that jquery must be somehow exposed to window as global variable. Authors of the library [provide example](https://github.com/RD17/react-trumbowyg#starter-guide) with `Webpack` but I don't have this in my project.

So I've installed jquery through `npm install` and tried to import it and set to the window variable like this (it didn't work):

```
import jquery from 'jquery';
window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
```

How can I setup `jquery` so that `trumbowyg` sees it? I've created my project with `create-react-app` command if it can help you.

Comment: I would not recommend using a library like that. It wraps jQuery within a react component. There are many WYSIWYG editors for react.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg

Comment: sounds like a bug on their end. their package.json should include a peerDependency on jquery. you could also simply add it to your DOM directly using the jquery CDN URL.

Comment: React and jQuery have completely different paradigms and are rarely compatible. If you are forced to use it, you will probably need to use `componentDidMount` and several hacks in the React side to allow jQuery work without interferences from React. For jQuery importing problem: `Webpack but I don't have this in my project`: What do you use to pack src files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others commented, you should choose other library which don't use jQuery. But 
 if you still want to use then you can do like the following:

```
import jquery from 'jquery'
import Trumbowyg from 'react-trumbowyg';
...
componentDidMount() { // hook the jQuery when component is mounted
  window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery;
}
render() {
  return <Trumbowyg id='react-trumbowyg'/>
}
```

If this still not working, then [require the plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52118753/2138752).

Comment: thanks, I've decided to use another library as others commented